# DOCSIS Upload speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, cable-modem

If I'm only interested in upload speed and my cable provider's plan offers a maximum upload speed of 35Mbps, is there any reason why I'd need a pricier 16x8 modem over a cheaper 8x4 modem?

Details:
My cable company is advertising a maximum upload speed of 35 Mbps.  My understanding is DOCSIS modems have an upload speed of ~25Mbps per channel.  Is there any reason why I'd need to get a DOCSIS 3.0 modem with more than 4 upload channels (4x25 = 100Mbps)?  In other words, I'm looking at a modem that's listed as 8x4, and if I'm only interested in upload speed, is there any reason I'd need the pricier 16x8 modem?  Please note I understand the 16 channels would give twice the download speed, but I'm only concerned with upload speed.